# Merge php array with dynamic key

Tags: php, arrays

If I query out the array like this form:

```
$arr1:

0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'a'
1 => 
     'id' => 2,
     'name' => 'b'
2 => 
     'id' => 3,
     'name' => 'c'
3 => 
     'id' => 4,
     'name' => 'd'
```

```
$arr2:

0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'parent' => '1a'
1 => 
     'id' => 2,
     'parent' => '2b'
2 => 
     'id' => 3,
     'parent' => '3c'
3 => 
     'id' => 4,
     'parent' => '4d'
```

When I need to merge these two I can done it using `foreach loop`.

The problem comes to when the `$arr1` is `dynamic data`(**need to use for pagination**), i can't merge well using array_merge due to `$arr2` is fixed data.

example: 
first time:

```
$arr1:
0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'a'
1 => 
     'id' => 2,
     'name' => 'b'
```

```
$arr2:

0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'parent' => '1a'
1 => 
     'id' => 2,
     'parent' => '2b'
2 => 
     'id' => 3,
     'parent' => '3c'
3 => 
     'id' => 4,
     'parent' => '4d'
```

second time:

```
$arr1:
0 => 
      'id' => 3,
      'name' => 'c'
1 => 
     'id' => 4,
     'name' => 'd'
```

```
$arr2:

0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'parent' => '1a'
1 => 
     'id' => 2,
     'parent' => '2b'
2 => 
     'id' => 3,
     'parent' => '3c'
3 => 
     'id' => 4,
     'parent' => '4d'
```

I had try using `foreach loop`

```
foreach($arr1 as $k => $value){
  $group[$k]['parent'] = $arr2[$k]['parent'];
  $group[$k]['name'] = $value['name'];
  $group[$k]['id'] = $value['id'];
}
```

It comes to the parent value does not change as `$key` is fixed.

The expected output should all the element in **1 array**:

```
0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'parent' => '1a'
      'name'='a'
1 => 
     'id' => 2,
     'parent' => '2b'
     'name'='b'
```

Comment: @NigelRen yes as long as i need a array with all element inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need...

The easiest way to do this is to re-index the second array with the ID as the key.  I use `array_column()` to do this.  Then use the id from `$arr1` to access the parent value from the newly indexed array...

```
$parent = array_column($arr2, 'parent', 'id');
$group = [];
foreach($arr1 as $k => $value){
    $group[$k]['parent'] = $parent[$value['id']];
    $group[$k]['name'] = $value['name'];
    $group[$k]['id'] = $value['id'];
}
```

In case `$arr2` has more information, just use `null` as the second parameter to `array_column()`.  Then you need to add the column name when you access that array...

```
$parent = array_column($arr2, null, 'id');
$group = [];
foreach($arr1 as $k => $value){
    $group[$k]['parent'] = $parent[$value['id']]['parent'];
    $group[$k]['name'] = $value['name'];
    $group[$k]['id'] = $value['id'];
}
```

Comment: cool answer btw if my ```$arr2``` had more than 2 values so how do I do? let said 
$arr2:
0 => 
      'id' => 1,
      'parent' => '1a',
     'child'   => '1aa',

Comment: I've added a second example which keeps all values in `$arr2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    $arr1[$k]['parent'] =  $arr2[$k]['parent'];
}


print_r( $arr1 );
```

Comment: I had tried before but it will not change when the second page in... because ```$arr1``` is dynamic changed